# Открыть файл по ссылке на сервере с virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Имеется сервер Python c Virtualenv и uWSGI, на котором исполняется скрипт, выводящий результаты в корневой `file.csv`. Необходимо чтобы этот файл был доступен по ссылке `site.ru/file.csv` Как я понял из гугла, для этого нужно настроить `urls.py` и `views.py` Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можете просто настроить nginx (apache или иной веб-сервер) для отдачи этого файла как статического.